# How can I JUnit test the RecordFilterStrategy from org.apache.springFramework.kafka.listener.adapter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, junit, spring-boot-test

I'm using the RecordFilterStrategy to filter out Kafka messages, but my JUnit test for the method is throwing an error; This is what the JUnit test looks like:

```
@Test
public void testFilter() {
MyObject myObject = new MyObject;
String key = "any";
MyObject.filter(ConsumerRecord<key, myObject>);
```

It is not recognizing ConsumerRecord even though I imported it like so;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
If I Mock the ConsumerRecord, and pass in myObject, I get error as well.
How can one create a JUnit test for this RecordFilterStrategy please?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting back?

Comment: myObject is unresolved when passed in to the ConsumerRecord